# Change path in web browser for pdf

Tags: c#

I have a C# forms app and a webBrowser from wich i want to open pdf. For me this works `C:\teachers.pdf` but i want to make it with installer and I want it like `teachers.pdf` and place it into the Debug folder. With text files it works but with this it doesn't. Can someone explain me why? 
here is the code i'm using `webBrowser1.Navigate(@"C:\teachers.pdf");`

Comment: Did you forget to remove C:\ ?

Comment: I want to make it as an installer so i want it with not fixed location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as said below and see if it works for you.

```
string currentDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

webBrowser1.Navigate(currentDirectory + "\\" + "test.pdf");
```

Comment: Always prefer `System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "test.pdf)`to plain string concatenation! No need to worry "do the path I'm working on end with a \ or not?"

Comment: Yes.......That's much better.